# Uploading file to DigitalOcean Spaces using s3 bucket from backend (nodeJs), get Access to only frontend (react)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I am trying to upload the file on **Digital Ocean** server from the backend (nodeJs) using `s3`. File uploaded successfully but I want that file only access by my frontend (React).

The code of uploading a file from **nodeJs** like this -

```js
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

        // Configure client for use with Spaces
        const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com');
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
        accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
        secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY'
        });

        // Add a file to a Space
        var params = {
        Body: "The contents of the file",
        Bucket: "my-new-space-with-a-unique-name",
        Key: "file.ext",
        ACL: 'public-read'
        };

        s3.upload(params, function (error, data) {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }
          return resolve(data.Location);
        });
```

I have no idea how to set the **correct permissions** on the s3 bucket.
I am new to the digital ocean so give steps from the beginning.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are only trying to access files in the frontend or are you trying to access images as well? I was able to solve the problem for accessing images and it might be accessible in the same way.